# How to get month interval using "datetime" in python?

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

As every month have different days in it, so i can't apply *timedelta*=30.

I want to get three variables

> month_start,
>
> month_end ,
>
> month_days = month_end - month_start

Which will be correspond to start date of month and end date of month. and their interval will be number of days in the month.

for instance , for march : month_days = 31, april : month_days = 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use calendar module to get days from months

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print calendar.monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]
31
```

For 2015 Feb month

```
>>> calendar.monthrange(2015, 2)
(6, 28)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html